# Use Prisma generated types as function parameter type

Tags: typescript, prisma

I'm playing around with Prisma ORM to see what the possibilities are. After creating the models and generating the PrismaClient I thought it would be possible to use the generated types and use them for variables and response types but that seems not to be the case.

```
...

model Invite {
  id        Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  gender    Gender
  firstName String     @map("first_name")
  lastName  String     @map("last_name")
  language  Language
  email     String     @unique
  token     String     @unique

  roleId Int  @map("role_id")
  role   Role @relation(fields: [roleId], references: [id])

  organisationId Int          @map("organisation_id")
  organisation   Organisation @relation(fields: [organisationId], references: [id])

  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt @map("updated_at")
  createdAt DateTime @default(now()) @map("created_at")

  @@map("invites")
}

...
```

Above I have an Invite model with a relation to the organisation and role models. In an invite service file I'm preparing all the input to create a new invite.

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import roleRepository from '../repositories/role.repository';
import organisationRepository from '../repositories/organisation.repository';
import generateToken from '../utils/helpers/generateToken';
import inviteRepository from '../repositories/invite.repository';

const createInvite = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const { body } = await validateInput(req);
    const { gender, firstName, lastName, email, language, roleId, organisationId } = body;

    const role = roleRepository.findRoleById(roleId);

    if (!role) {
        throw new Error('Role does not exist');
    }

    const organisation = organisationRepository.findOrganisationById(organisationId);

    if (!organisation) {
        throw new Error('Organisation does not exist');
    }

    const token = generateToken();

    const invite = inviteRepository.createInvite({
        gender,
        firstName,
        lastName,
        email,
        language,
        role: role,
        organisation: organisation,
        token,
    });

    await mailService.sendInviteEmail(invite);

    res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Invite created successfully',
    });
};
```

In the `createInvite` function of the `inviteRepository` file I'm trying to use a generated type of Prisma,`InviteCreateInput`.

```
const createInvite = async (inviteData: Prisma.InviteCreateInput): Promise<Invite> => {
    return db.invite.create({
        data: {
            gender: inviteData.gender,
            firstName: inviteData.firstName,
            lastName: inviteData.lastName,
            language: inviteData.language,
            email: inviteData.email,
            token: inviteData.token,
            role: {
                connect: {
                    id: inviteData.role
                }
            },
            organisation: {
                connect: {
                    id: inviteData.organisation,
                }
            }
        },
    });
};
```

[Prisma recommends this 'safe' way of Input](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/advanced-type-safety#generated-uncheckedinput-types) but the `InviteCreateInput` looks like this

```
  export type InviteCreateInput = {
    gender: Gender
    firstName: string
    lastName: string
    language: string
    email: string
    token: string
    updatedAt?: Date | string
    createdAt?: Date | string
    role: RoleCreateNestedOneWithoutInviteInput
    organisation: OrganisationCreateNestedOneWithoutInvitesInput
  }
```

and `RoleCreateNestedOneWithoutInviteInput` looks like this:

```
  export type RoleCreateNestedOneWithoutInviteInput = {
    create?: XOR<RoleCreateWithoutInviteInput, RoleUncheckedCreateWithoutInviteInput>
    connectOrCreate?: RoleCreateOrConnectWithoutInviteInput
    connect?: RoleWhereUniqueInput
  }
```

Since this type is expecting a create, connectOrCreate or connect it seems to be unusable as function parameter type for this function (Also wondering in what approach this type could be usable). I found `InviteUncheckedCreateInput` as possible type to use but since Prisma is not recommending using the `unchecked` types I'm not sure if this is a good approach.

Someone with experience using Prisma types as function paramater type or is it better to create a type myself?

Answer (score 2):

The reason Prisma suggest it's "safer" is because they assume that you may not be checking for the `roleId` or the `organisationId` (which you are doing with `findRoleById` and `findOrganisationById`.

***For performance***, I would remove the extra queries - `findRoleById` and `findOrganisationById` and write your middleware like so:

```
const createInvite = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { body } = await validateInput(req);
  const { gender, firstName, lastName, email, language, roleId, organisationId } = body;

  const token = generateToken();

  try {
    const invite = await inviteRepository.createInvite({
      gender,
      firstName,
      lastName,
      email,
      language,
      token,
      role: {
        connect: {
          id: roleId,
        },
      },
      organisation: {
        connect: {
          id: organisationId,
        },
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    // handle the errors from no organisationId nor roleId existing
    // next(Error) or something similar
  }

  await mailService.sendInviteEmail(invite);

  res.status(201).json({
    message: 'Invite created successfully',
  });
};
```

You could also clean up your `createInvite` function:

```
const createInvite = async (data: Prisma.InviteCreateInput): Promise<Invite> => {
  return db.invite.create({
    data,
  });
};
```